# Run a Javascript function to populate a table and then parse the HTML page using Jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, jsoup

I am working on a project for my job that allows the user to parse a given HTML page, which provides information on a lead. The problem I am facing, however, is that the webpage displays this lead information within a table that gets populated, from what I can understand, from a Javascript function, so when Jsoup parses the document, it cannot find the table or any of its contents. Here is the HTML I am specifically looking at:

```
<table class="none" align="center" bgcolor="white" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr class="tm_tt_ftr1">
        <td class="typedata1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">Name</td>
        <td class="typedata1">Phone</td>
        <td class="typedata1x" colspan="2">$$$ Summary&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
        <td class="typedata1" title="Lookup this name historical"><center>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:Pop_Up('X','Testerson',
        'Testerson','Tes','Test');">
            N</a></center></td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">&nbsp;Testerson, Test           </td>
        <td class="typedata1">
            <b><a href="rtrpt.cgi?DATE_OPT=US_TERSE
            &amp;RT_SCRIPT=mkcnt/cnt_lookup_phone_cgi.rt&amp;JDATE=TODAY
            &amp;DATE1=TODAY&amp;DATE2=TODAY&amp;QSRC=ALL&amp;DETAIL=N
            &amp;QPAC=631&amp;QPRE=384&amp;QPNUM=6191" title="Search phone history this number" target="_new">P1:</a></b>
            <a href="rtrpt.cgi?
            DATE_OPT=X&amp;RT_SCRIPT=mkcnt/lead_phn_cgi.rt
            &amp;LEAD=011876280" title="Additional phone numbers this lead" target="_new">
            <b>222-222-2222</b></a>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">Charge&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="10%">    49.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
        <td class="typedata1" title="Lookup this name historical" colspan="1"><center>
            &nbsp;</center></td>
            <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1">&nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <b>               </b>
        </td>
        <td class="fd_tt_body_neg">Paid&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="fd_tt_body_neg" colspan="1">    49.00</td> <!--This is what I am looking to extract -->
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">9 Daniel Ln&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="1">Email
    <a id="ld_email" href="mailto:testtesterson@gmail.com?subject='L11876280'">
        testtesterson@gmail.com</a>
        </td>
        <td>Due&nbsp;</td>
        <td>     0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="1">CB  @ -------</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="1">1B&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
        <td class="typedata1"><center> 111</center></td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="3">Springfield NY 11953</td>
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="1">Comm:&nbsp;1314379</td>
        <td colspan="2"><center>DC: ., .</center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tm_tt_body">
        <td class="typedata1" colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
```

As stated above, Jsoup cannot find this table, or any of its contents at all. The div containing this table has a Javascript function as follows:

```
<script language="Javascript">
 function UpdateDiv(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://flag.60north.net/cgi-bin/rtrpt_tabpanel2G_New.cgi", 
    type: 'POST', 
    async: true, 
    dataType: 'html', 
    data: "RT_SCRIPT=telemkt/prime/leadcgiUpDate_New.rt&DATE_OPT=X&DETAIL=N&LNUM=" + $("input#LNUM").val(), 
    timeout: 90000, 
    success: 
     function(retData){ 
        $(".Lead_Info").html(retData);

     }
  });
}
</script>
```

From what I'm understanding from this, these functions get called in order to populate the table. What I am looking to do is have a way to run the function in order to populate the page with the lead's info, and then parse it using Jsoup. From my personal research, I found that Selenium API allows for executing Javascript functions within an HTML document, however, I don't think this is what will solve my problem. Whatever Selenium runs, from what I understand, won't have an affect on Jsoup parsing the HTML when it goes to connect to the url and retrieve the document. Obviously, if Jsoup had the ability to do so, I would have Jsoup run the function and then parse, but that is not an available feature. What would be the next best solution in order to get this lead information to display?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get(url);
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

 js.executeScript("UpdateDiv();");
```

Then You extract html from WebDriver and pass to JSoup for parsing and other actions:

```
String html = driver.getPageSource();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: this in theory should work, however, I'm getting a SessionNotCreatedException when running my code. I believe this is either due to either my site requiring a basic authentication (which from my understanding isn't currently supported by Selenium API) or a bug with my current version of FireFox (had to use the FirefoxDriver since I don't have chrome on my work computer).